# Role of portal-kernel and portal-impl

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

In Liferay 7, what is the conceptual difference between [portal-kernel](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/master/portal-kernel) and [portal-impl](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/master/portal-impl)?

From the name only, it would sound like kernel is a kind of foundation, and impl builds around it with UI/etc. But actually kernel also contains [UI](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/master/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/struts) [code](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/master/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/servlet/taglib) and code that [looks rather annex](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/editor/EditorModeUtil.java).

- Both have interfaces, implementations and unit tests.
- portal-kernel has 500 directories, 4766 files.
- portal-impl has 947 directories, 4252 files

Where is the intended line between portal-kernel and portal-impl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

portal-kernel has public interfaces and implementations that you typically need when interfacing with Liferay. These can be util-classes or just service interfaces.

portal-impl is considered implementation detail - you shouldn't depend on it and it's not intended for anybody to change. *If* you decide you *really* have to change anything in portal-impl, then there's no assumption that the implementation stays stable even with the slightest edit in the next release. Anything goes, no stability promise is given.